# Dictionary of swift classes with strings

Tags: swift

I have this class Identity and a dictionary of instances of them with Strings as keys. I want to access one of the instances by a string and change some of its properties. I'm trying to use a switch statement to access the instances in the dictionary depending on the value of a string.

```
class Identity {
    let provider: String
    let uid: String?
    let token: String?
    let name: String?

    init(provider: String){
        self.provider = provider
        self.uid = nil
        self.token = nil
        self.name = nil
    }
}

var identities = [String:Identity]()

identities["twitter"] = Identity(provider: "twitter")

identities["twitter"].uid = "131241241241"

identities["twitter"].name = "@freedrull"

let provider: String = "twitter"

var i: Identity? {
    switch provider {
    case "twitter":
        return identities["twitter"] as Identity?
    case "facebook":
        return identities["facebook"] as Identity?
    case "soundcloud":
        return identities["soundcloud"] as Identity?
    default:
        return nil
    }
}

if i != nil {
    i.name = "tony"
}
```

I get an error about assigning `i.name` to "tony". Do I need to cast `i` to an Identity somehow? I thought it already was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `i` as an Optional:

```
var i: Identity? // ...
```

So it's still an Optional. It's not an Identity. It's an Optional wrapping an Identity. But you can't *do* anything to an Optional - until you unwrap it. Unwrap it, to get at the Identity. You have:

```
if i != nil {
    i.name = "tony"
}
```

Instead:

```
if let i = i {
    i.name = "tony"
}
```

Or:

```
if i != nil {
    i!.name = "tony"
}
```

Both are ways of unwrapping the Optional.

Or, test and unwrap all in one move:

```
i?.name = "tony"
```

Then you'll have a new problem; you have declared `name` as a constant. You can't change a constant! You have:

```
let name: String?
```

Instead:

```
var name: String?
```

[By the way, much of this code is redundant:

```
init(provider: String){
    self.provider = provider
    self.uid = nil
    self.token = nil
    self.name = nil
}
```

`uid`, `token`, and `name` are all Optionals, so they are *already* nil. You can cut those three lines.]

Comment: I believe you can also do: `i?.name = "tony"` as well without having 3 lines of code.

Comment: @theMonster Sure, I'll throw it in, why not?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, still getting the error though. I tried both methods. Playground execution failed: MyPlayground.playground:39:9: error: cannot assign to 'name' in 'i'

Comment: That did it! Thanks. You can't change `let` variables?

Comment: I had no idea honestly